# convert a pointer to a reverse vector iterator in STL

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have

```
sort(arr, arr+n, pred);
```

How do I sort in reverse order?

Comment: Is pred a predicate you wrote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There also seems to be a possibility to use reverse iterators ... except using the reversed predicate might be easier, except perhaps when the type doesn't implement `operator>` :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = { 3, 2, 5, 4 };
    std::sort(std::reverse_iterator<int*>(arr + 4), std::reverse_iterator<int*>(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're given `pred` (i.e. you can't get inside it to reverse the order), something like:

```
std::sort(arr, arr+n, boost:bind<bool>(pred, _2, _1));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `greater` from the standard library which calls `operator>` automatically for the type you want to sort.

```
#include <funcitonal>
.....
sort(arr, arr+n, greater<Type>()); // Type could be double for example
```

Answer (score 2):

Negate the return value of `pred`.

Comment: I think you need more than this.  Pred needs to be a strict weak ordering, e.g., like < not <=.  If you negate a strict weak ordering you don't get another strict weak ordering: negating < turns into >= not >.

Comment: David's right, you need to reverse the operands, not negate the return value.

Answer (score 1):

As alrady said, you should provde a reversed predicate. If you can't for some reasons (like pure laziness), you can always first sort then reverse :

```
sort(arr, arr+n, pred);
reverse( arr, arr+n );
```

That would be more work for the computer but it's clear and does the job. If you need speed performance for this sort, use the reversed predicate solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Quite Easy i seems**

```
std::sort(myVec.rbegin(),myVec.rend());


int main() 
{
    typedef std::vector<int> vecType;
    vecType myVec;
    for(int a=0;a<20;a++)
    {
        myVec.push_back((rand()%100));
    }
    std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    cout<<"\n---------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::sort(myVec.rbegin(),myVec.rend());
    std::copy(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort(arr, arr+n, std::not1(pred));
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/

Comment: Wrong: pred(a,a) will return false, as it should, but `not1(pred(a,a))` incorrectly returns true. This may cause `sort()` to hang.